# How to create a makefile from a C program?

Tags: c, makefile, header

Hiya, as part of an assessment I have to hand in a code which requires a few non-standard libraries.  In order to save submitting the header files and the code I would like to form a 'makefile' with the code and required add-ons sort of 'bundled' together.  I have absolutely no idea idea how to go about doing this though and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here's the manual for GNU make: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction

Comment: sounds more like you want a tar file to me ?

Comment: `make make`? I must have missed something

Answer (score 2):

A makefile does not look to be what you are looking for. You cannot bundle things into a makefile. Think of a makefile as a file accompanying your source and header files that will contain the recipe. It will tell *how* to build your program using all the other files.

Comment: So there isnt a way of only submitting one file?

Comment: @Jack: Make a tarbal: `tar czfv project.tgz project_directory`. You typically clean up in there first, of course (no point in sending editor backup files, object files for the wrong machine, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing specifics, I can only point you in the right direction. This site, although not very pleasing to the eye, is fairly easy to understand:

[Makefile Tutorial](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/)

[This](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) is the GNU manual page for 'make'

Answer (score 0):

Just package your source code and list the requirements in a description somewhere.

For example:

> To use my program you need the curses library.

Let the responsability of getting/installing/configuring the required libraries be with the user of your source.